# form_for non-AR model - fields_for Array attribute doesn't iterate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I'm having trouble getting `fields_for` to work on an Array attribute of a non-ActiveRecord model.

Distilled down, I have to following:

models/parent.rb

```
class Parent
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Translation

  attr_accessor :bars
end
```

controllers/parent_controller.rb

```
def new_parent
  @parent = Parent.new

  @parent.bars = ["hello", "world"]
  render 'new_parent'
end
```

views/new_parent.html.haml

```
= form_for @parent, :url => new_parent_path do |f|
  = f.fields_for :bars, @parent.bars do |r|
    = r.object.inspect
```

With the code as above, my page contains `["hello", "world"]` - that is, the result of `inspect` called on the Array assigned to `bars`. (With `@parent.bars` omitted from the `fields_for` line, I just get `nil` displayed).

How can I make `fields_for` behave as for an AR association - that is, perform the code in the block once for each member of my `bars` array?

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't think anyone else had tried to do this! Thanks... a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the correct technique is:

```
= form_for @parent, :url => new_parent_path do |f|
  - @parent.bars.each do |bar|
    = f.fields_for "bars[]", bar do |r|
      = r.object.inspect
```

Quite why it can't be made to Just Work I'm not sure, but this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it can be done without the need of each:

```
= form_for @parent, :url => new_parent_path do |f|
  = f.fields_for :bars do |r|
    = r.object.inspect
```

You need to set some methods that are expected in the parent class to identify the collection.

```
class Parent
  def bars_attributes= attributes
  end
end
```

And you also will need to make sure that the objects in the array respond to persisted (so you cannot use strings) :(

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the fields_for and added multiple: true

```
= form_for @parent, :url => new_parent_path do |f|
  - @parent.bars.each_with_index do |bar, i|
    = f.text_field :bars, value: bar, multiple: true, id: "bar#{i}"
```