# Get an array from a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to design a form for a `account` resource. In that form, i need to collect some set of ids as an array in the `params` hash in attribute called `relationships`.

So the final `params[account]` hash from the POST request should be like:

```
{:name => 'somename', :relationships => ["123", "23", "23445"]}
```

How shall I design the `form_for` fields? I tried this, but didn't work:

```
<%= form_for @account do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <% @eligible_parents.each do |p| %>
        <%= f.check_box "relationships", nil, :value => p.id  %>
        <b><%= p.name %></b><br/>
      </span>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Number of elements in `@eligible_parents` varies every time.

`relationships` is neither an association nor an attribute in `account` model.

I have to use virtual attributes but I need to fill in an array from a form.

Please help. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible Answer/Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271940/form-for-non-ar-model-fields-for-array-attribute-doesnt-iterate It's a bit different, but I think the underlying technique is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need a `fields_for` in your view, just use `:relationships` as the `record_name` then provide an object.

```
<%= form_for @account do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <% fields_for :relationships, @eligible_parents do |p| %>
        <%= p.check_box "relationships", nil, :value => p.object.id  %>
        <b><%= p.object.name %></b><br/>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Documentation here: [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Comment: thanks! where do i learn more about these! Neither rails guides, nor popular books talk about this kind of special usages.

Comment: I found this out while trying to solve one of my problems, this particular thing I ended up looking at documentation and the [Rails source on github](https://github.com/rails/rails), I ended up finding little gems like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send array of values just use [] in name attributes.In your case just use

```
<%= f.check_box "relationships", {}, :value => p.id, :name => "relationships[]"   %>
```

Comment: undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `<%= check_box_tag 'ip_address[]', ip_res.ip_address, false %>`   `ip_address` is attr of my model IpResource

Comment: Its my previous code.. after porting it into format like your answer, I got above `undefined method 'merge' for nil:NilClass` error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10154/discussion-between-raj-and-soundar)

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be the cleanest way...

If you are working with straight data and want to send back an array without using any of these @objects:

```
<%= form_for :team do |t| %>
  <%= t.fields_for 'people[]', [] do |p| %>
    First Name: <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
    Last Name: <%= p.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

your params data should return like this:

```
"team" => {
  "people" => [
    {"first_name" => "Michael", "last_name" => "Jordan"},
    {"first_name" => "Steve", "last_name" => "Jobs"},
    {"first_name" => "Barack", "last_name" => "Obama"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: im trying to do this with an array of non-active record models but it keeps asking for the "id" and giving me "undefined method `id`"

Comment: @dtc you are probably doing a .id which should be ['id'] if you're working with non-active record models

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in something similar. My issue was how to pass the input name to a partial to resolve it as a hash using the rails `form_for` helper.

So, my solutions was something like this:

`= render 'my_partial', form: form, name: "item_ids[item.id]"`

So, this gonna render an html like this:

`<input class="form-control" name="products[items_ids[1]]" id="products_items_ids[1]">`

The number `1` is the `item.id`, this is how HTML understand that you gonna pass an array or hash, all depends your config.

So, the params gonna look like this:

`"items_ids"=>{"1"=>"1"}`

This is working for me with an `form_object + virtus`