# Is it possible to compare form submitted strings in array to string values in a model database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sqlite, model-view-controller

This is more going into rails theory. I want to compare strings submitted by a user to strings in a populated model. Is this possible? Even if it is possible would it be better to create a user in putted model and compare the strings from there?

Is there any documentation on how to achieve this

My names are kind of wonky, I adapted this from a microposts tutorial to try and be a dna(user input) --> rna (mrna db) sequencer (which i understand is very bad form)

users/new.html.erb(renders)/_form.hrml.erb

```
<%= form_for :user do |t| %>
  <%= t.fields_for 'inputdna[]', [] do |p| %>
     dna <%= p.text_field :dna %>
  <% end %>
  <%= t.submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    dna_options = 'ttt, ttc, tta'.split(',')

    #validates :dna_options, presence: true

    # returns true|false
    def dna_valid?(user_input)
        user.input.each
           return false if unless dna_options.include? user_input
    end
    return true
 end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    # GET /users
    # GET /users.json
    def index
         @users = User.new # not touched, however the convention would normally be User.new
    end

    def new 
         User.create(full: params['user']['full'], dna: params['user']['inputdna']['dna'], mrna: params['user']['mrna']) if User.dna_valid? params['user']['inputdna']['dna']
    end
 end
```

seed.rb for users model

```
User.create(full: "phenylalanine", dna: "ttt", mrna: "uuu")
User.create(full: "phenylalanine", dna: "ttc", mrna: 'uuc')
User.create(full: "leucine", dna: 'tta', mrna: 'uua')
```

Comment: The user model needs to have a 'do |dna|' afer the .each and then the user_input after the .include? needs to be changed to 'dna'. See below for the update.

Comment: Shout if that worked/or not

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to compare strings, there are few methods to do so, and the difficulty around user inputs that may prove a challenge.

Assuming you had a model such as:

```
Class SomeStrings
    @@some_string = 'String Answer'
end
```

You could compare this to user input from some params like so:

```
params['user_input'] == SomeStrings.some_string
```

This will return a boolean (true|false) for use in if/case statements.

Now, to ensure that the inputs match regardless of case you have two simple options:

```
params['user_input'].downcase == SomeStrings.some_string.downcase
```

or

```
params['user_input'].casecmp(SomeStrings.some_string)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-casecmp

The latter approach with casecmp is alot faster than downcasing both string parts.

Now in this example I used a class variable @@some_string, however you could apply the same logic to any model with variables/methods that return a string. This model could be an activerecord, or other ORM record, or just a class.

Shout if you want anymore input.

<>

If you wish to pre-populate this model with something on a user by user basis you will need create some level of persistence. This could be in your code 'hard coded', a database or the session. For example, if you want to compare some users input against one of a list of 5 words stored in the session you could do this:

```
session['words_to_compare_to'] = Words.generate_five_random_words unless session['words_to_compare_to']
```

you could create a method on your model that creates words, and this would assign them into the session. This means each user would get some words to compare to which are random per user. This could be your method:

```
class Words
  @@words_list = 'help, go, north, fred, mimi, the, and, elf'.split(",")

  def generate_five_random_words
     words_to_return = []    
     5.times{ words_to_return << @@words_list.sample }
     return words_to_return
  end
end
```

Then to compare the input you receive to see if it is within the 5 random words in your controller you could do this:

```
session['words_to_compare_to'].include? params['user_input'].downcase
```

We are using downcase here as all of our words list are lower case. This returns a boolean true|false if the user input is found within the array of 5 words. I hope this provides something that you can reuse.

*** Update following code addition to question ***

I am going to assume that the user fills out the text field and submits it to a route /user/create. I am assuming the purpose is to check that the 3 letter dna that the user submitted is within an acceptable dna list.

So to start, lets add the acceptable dna combinations to the user model:

```
Class User
  dna_options = 'ttt, ttc, tta'.split(',')

   # returns true|false
  def self.dna_valid?(user_input)
     dna_options.include? user_input
  end
end
```

Now, depending on which ORM you are using, you can also use validators for this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

To use the above within your controller you could do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @users = Array.new # not touched, however the convention would normally be User.new
   end

   def create 
      User.create(full: params['user']['full'], dna: params['user']['inputdna']['dna'], mrna: params['user']['mrna']) if User.dna_valid? params['user']['inputdna']['dna']
   end
end
```

Now, I have made lots of assumptions here, as your code is missing the same entities as your model, however I hope you see what can be done. If params['user']['inputdna'] returns an array, you could change the code to:

```
if user.dna_valid? params['user']['inputdna']
```

and change the boolean operator within the model to:

```
   # returns true|false
   # expects user_input to be an array
  def self.dna_valid?(user_input)
     user.input.each do |dna|
        return false if unless dna_options.include? dna
     end
     return true
  end
```

This returns true if all the entities are found within the dna_options, or false if one of them does not

Comment: I am having some major difficulty wrapping my head around the adding user input to the array, I can't seem to find much documentation on this.
I was attempting to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155805/get-an-array-from-a-rails-form
For testing purposes right now I think I will just compare with booleans. I have my model with my scaffolding set up, where should I initialize and store the array at? I thought about attemping to set that up in my _form.html.erb but would doing that be a mistake?

Comment: Taking a step back, I have been searching for some type of tutorial or information and it doesn't seem like there is anything out there. Is there some other better way to do this?

Comment: When you say adding the input to an array, this can be done like this:
array = []
array << param['user_input']

Just taking a look at the link to see if I can help

Comment: Just as clarity, can you provide some code of what you are doing. The link refers to the params coming back as an array. If you paste in the params as they come back I can help you get to the ones you want.

Comment: Posted code, I deleted much of my auto generated code because I wanted my db model to inaccessible by users at the time since I seeded it. Also, I would have to parse the string into 3 char groups to compare to the db, I was just going to worry about that later. Just noticed you added more code so I will fiddle with that.

Comment: Updated based on code, shout if I'm missing the part that you are stuck on.

Comment: Your assumptions seem correct, I am getting a syntax error" unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end" on line 10 of the controller. But I can't immediately identify errors in your code. Long ago, I deleted all the CRUD implementation from the users_controller so create no longer exists could this be the cause?

Comment: That syntax error is thrown if you are missing an 'end'. Can you paste your entire controller please.

Comment: Added the users controller. I copied and pasted all the CRUD implementation along with the methods you gave me, it still had the same error

Comment: lol, apologies, but user class was missing some tweaks. It did not have a do on the loop, and thus was confused by the end.

Comment: made the changes, I am receiving an error from the form file. NoMethodError in Users#new. undefined method `dna' for []:Array. It seems like it's so close to working!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for only comparing and finding exact matches, then this is what I used.

```
    all_users = params[:user][:dna].map do |u|
        User.find_by(name: u)
    end
```

Here you're getting the response from the form submission in the "params[:user]", then it is comparing that response to the User table using the "User.find_by(name: u)" and assigning matches to "all_users" through the map loop.

The problem you might encounter here is if the form submission does not find an entry in the model, which will then return a "nil".  This simple logic does not deal with "nil" returns.