# Rails GPS coordinates as an array from a form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, gps, actioncontroller

I have setup [gmaps-autocomplete-rails](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails) gem in my application, and I have an UI callback that can let me set the GPS coordinates to an input

```
function autocompleteMap(){
        var completer;
        completer = new GmapsCompleter({
            ...
            updateUI: function(address, latLng) {
                $("#myObject_coordinates").val(
                  "["+latLng.lat()+", "+latLng.lng()+"]" 
                )
            }
        });
    }
```

My mongoid model accept coordinates as an array to be used with the geocoder gem. Is there a practical way to pass the lat/lng as an array via input fields ? Some SO answers suggested to use

```
f.text_field(:coordinates, multiple: true)
```

but I cannot figure out how I should fill the value so it is interpreted as an array in the controller (and preserve lat/Lng order)

[Get an array from a rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155805/get-an-array-from-a-rails-form) form doesn't help in my case, since I am using javascript to fill a single input (or should I set it up to fill two inputs ?)

Right now with the above js function, the associated rails params becomes

```
params[:my_object][:coordinates] # => ["[x, y]"]
# Wanted: [x, y]
```

Do I have to parse the string manually as an array, or is there a trick ?

Also, this input needs to be sanitized and the numbers ocnverted to floats, any guideline, protip on how to do that "neatly" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 2 fields and you probably want to make them hidden.

#### View

```
f.hidden_field(:coordinates, multiple: true, class: 'lat', id: 'lat')
f.hidden_field(:coordinates, multiple: true, class: 'lng', id: 'lng')
```

#### JavaScript

```
// ...
    updateUI: function(address, latLng) {
      $('input.lat').val(latLng.lat());
      $('input.lng').val(latLng.lng());
    }
// ...
```

#### Controller

```
# Will receive it as an array
params[:my_object][:coordinates]               # => [x, y]
```

Comment: Had a left over script. Updated my answer. I would love to know why the answer has been down voted though...

Comment: Well it's not me. I'm trying your solution right now, will report just after.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris, that's ok. I was just putting it out there for the down voter. Didn't mean you, sorry. Was wondering if I made some mistake that and don't realise.

Comment: No worries. Just tried it out and it works perfect, thanks. There is a duplicate ID in the HTML because of the two hidden_fields, but I guess there's no way around it ?

Comment: You can force Rails to use your `id`s, by specifying them as params, just like `class`. I'll update my answer.